# Why is "0" == “” false in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, types, compare, coercion, type-coercion

In the ES5 spec, clauses 11.9.3.4-5 say:

> If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the
> comparison x == ToNumber(y).
>  If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is
> Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

How I understand this is:
"" is coerced to number and becomes 0 -> **"0"==0**
then recursively "0" is coerced to number and becomes also 0 -> **0==0**
so the output must be **true**.
but it is **false**. 
can you explain why?

```js
console.log("0"=="")
```

Answer (score 1):

`"0"` is a string. So is `""`. No type coercion is involved.

The string composed of `0` (a single character, character code 48) is not equivalent to the empty string.

If the `'0'` was `0` instead, the process would occur as you're describing it:

```js
console.log(0 == "")
```

The empty string gets turned into a number - 0 - and then `0 === 0` evaluates to `true`.-

(but I'd suggest never using sloppy equality regardless - always use strict equality and you won't have to worry about any of this silliness)

Comment: ahh, so much reading about coercion, that stopped thinking straight :D anyway, thanks for the answer, saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

The *very first clause* in [7.12.4 *Abstract Equality Comparison*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) is:

> 1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>    a. Return the result of performing Strict Equality Comparison x === y.

[7.12.5 *Strict Equality Comparison*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) reads, in its entirety:

> 1. If Type(x) is different from Type(y), return false.
> 2. If Type(x) is Number or BigInt, then
>    a. Return ! Type(x)::equal(x, y).
> 3. Return ! SameValueNonNumeric(x, y).

Since the types of `"0"` and `""` are both String, neither case #1 nor case #2 applies, so we go to [7.2.12 *SameValueNonNumeric(x, y)*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluenonnumeric):

> 1. Assert: Type(x) is not Number or BigInt.
> 2. Assert: Type(x) is the same as Type(y).
> 3. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
> 4. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
> 5. If Type(x) is String, then.
>    a. If x and y are exactly the same sequence of code units (same length and same code units at corresponding indices), return true; otherwise, return false.
> 6. If Type(x) is Boolean, then
>    a. If x and y are both true or both false, return true; otherwise, return false.
> 7. If Type(x) is Symbol, then
>    a. If x and y are both the same Symbol value, return true; otherwise, return false.
> 8. If x and y are the same Object value, return true. Otherwise, return false.

It should be easy to see that case #5 applies here:

> 5. If Type(x) is String, then.
>    a. If x and y are exactly the same sequence of code units (same length and same code units at corresponding indices), return true; otherwise, return false.

It should also be easy to see that `"0"` and `""` are not exactly the same sequence of code units, since they have neither the same length nor the same code units at corresponding indices.

Therefore, the result is `false`, as per the second alternative of 7.2.12, clause 5, subclause a.